# Link errors using Homebrew's Boost::Log in OSX El Capitan

Tags: c++, macos, boost, homebrew

OSX 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

I'm getting link errors while building the [first example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html) from the Boost::Log tutorial.

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main(int, char*[])
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(debug) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(fatal) << "A fatal severity message";

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the diagnostics:

```
$ c++ trivial_log_test.cpp 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data::destroy(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record_view::public_data const*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record::reset() in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::auto_release::~auto_release() in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::unhandled_exception_count()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::record_pump(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>&, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&) in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::record_pump<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >::~record_pump() in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::open_record(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::attribute_set const&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::push_record_unlocked(boost::rv<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record>&) in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level) in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::logger::get()", referenced from:
      _main in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
  "boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::core::get_logging_enabled() const", referenced from:
      boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::basic_composite_logger<char, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex>, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::features<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::sources::severity<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void, void> >::open_record<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&) in trivial_log_test-6968b8.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Several similar questions said that the following gave useful information:

```
$ clang++ -E -x c++ - -v < /dev/null
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.11.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name - -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 253.9 -v -dwarf-column-info -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2 -stdlib=libc++ -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/chap/private/cpp/BOOST_TESTING/log_test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 176 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.11.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o - -x c++ -
clang -cc1 version 7.0.2 based upon LLVM 3.7.0svn default target x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/c++/v1"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1
 /usr/local/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/7.0.2/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /usr/include
 /System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
 /Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 332 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>" 2
```

Homebrew is installed and up-to-date. I reinstalled Boost:

```
$ brew reinstall boost
==> Reinstalling boost
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/boost-1.60.0_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-1.60.0_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring boost-1.60.0_1.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1: 11,139 files, 436.0M
```

In other similar questions about link errors using the Boost libraries, a common solution was to run `bootstrap.sh` to build the `b2` executable to compile some libraries. However, these people installed Boost without using Homebrew. Homebrew's installation of Boost looks different than the directory structure that's described by the [Boost 'getting started' page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#the-boost-distribution) - notably in that it doesn't contain either the `bootstrap.sh` script or the `b2` binary. This makes me think that `brew install boost` has taken care of it.

Can someone suggest a next step?

UPDATE 1: Corrected statement about bootstrap.sh and b2.

Comment: Read the "getting started" docs? They describe a script called `bootstrap.sh`, which builds `b2`. (which is an executable, not a script)

Comment: @MarshallClow my forgetfulness - I have corrected my statement. I meant bootstrap.sh script. Neither that nor b2 is in the Homebrew installation.

Comment: The reason that you're getting link errors is that Boost.Log is not a header-only library. You have to link it into your executable, after building the boost libraries. However, that doesn't help with your `bootstrap.sh` or `b2` problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, provided by someone on the Homebrew mailing list, was to compile my program using the following flags:

```
c++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK -lboost_log-mt trivial_log_test.cpp
```

Since I got the Boost "bottle", I got prebuilt versions of the binary libraries. No need for `bootstrap.sh` / `b2`.