# How to build and link Boost.Serialization on MacOS

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm building a client-server application in C++ using Boost, a colleague of mine is coding the server in Ubuntu and he's using Boost.Serialization but I'm unable to run it because it doesn't find that library, besides I also need the library for the client. To build and link it to the project he's only created a CMAKE file like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(RemoteBackup_Server)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread" )

add_executable(RemoteBackup_Server User.cpp main.cpp server.cpp server.h connection_handler.cpp connection_handler.h)


find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization filesystem)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(RemoteBackup_Server ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Which compiles and links the library with no efforts.
I'm using MacOS, I've installed Boost using Homebrew and I've tried to follow the guide in the Boost official site: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary
but I don't have `bootstrap.sh` and `b2` (commands mentioned in the guide) to build the libraries and I've searched everywhere on the internet and still got no clue on how to proceed. Any help?

Comment: The first command listed in the instructions is `cd`. You do not have this command?

Comment: One reason I asked about `cd` is because I suspect you could be more precise in your problem description. Another reason is that the other commands (`bootstrap.sh` and `b2`) are part of a Boost installation... What precisely have you tried, and what precisely was the result?

Comment: Of course I have `cd` but I don't have `bootstrap.sh` and `b2` which led me think that maybe Homebrew doesn't install everything about Boost. I couldn't try anything since I can't go on with that guide and I haven't find anything else suitable.

Comment: You say "of course", but your post could have been read to suggest otherwise. It's good to have all relevant details *in the post itself*. This makes it easier both for the people answering and the other people with the same problem. (Think about it. When you searched everywhere on the internet, did you search for *"the commands it says"* or for *"bootstrap.sh"*? How will the next person benefit from your experience if your question cannot be found?) I've taken the liberty of updating your question.

Comment: Speaking of searching: [Link errors using Homebrew's Boost::Log in OSX El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36183351). You might not need to build the libraries. Then again, that answer is over 4 years old.

Comment: Thanks a lot for everything, I still have to learn how to ask questions properly. I swear I looked for an answer for an hour and didn't find anything, I think that the question you linked would have resolved my problem but since I was in a hurry I uninstalled Boost from Homebrew and followed the Boost guide, downloading it from their site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that Homebrew only installs header libraries of Boost. To me, the easiest way to install everything was downloading the complete Boost archive from their website and then follow the instructions from here https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#prepare-to-use-a-boost-library-binary and then link them in the CMAKE file as follows:

```
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR prefix/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR prefix/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS libraries_needed REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Project_Name ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Where:
*prefix* is the path of the installation that you specify with the `--prefix` flag when using `./bootstrap.sh`,
*libraries_needed* is the list of the libraries you need separated by a space, for example `filesystem serialization`,
*Project_Name* is the name of your project, specified in the `project()` command in the CMAKE file.